# Mongrel Rails error: RoutingError (No route matches "/://0" with {:method=>:get}):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I keep seeing this error in my rails production log, any ideas what the issue is?
Im running rails on apache with mongrel clusters.
RoutingError (No route matches "/://0" with {:method=>:get}):

Not sure what attempted url is causing the error.

Edit: Heres my routes.rb file

ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

```
map.signout '/account/signout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'
map.signin '/account/signin', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
map.signup '/account/signup', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new'

map.change_password '/account/change_password', :controller => 'users', :action => 'change_password'
map.forgot_password '/account/forgot_password', :controller => 'users', :action => 'forgot_password'
map.reset_password '/account/reset_password/:id', :controller => 'users', :action => 'reset_password'   

map.preferences '/preferences', :controller => 'preferences', :action => 'index'
map.dashboard '/dashboard', :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'index'
map.account '/account', :controller => 'account', :action => 'index'
map.affiliate '/affiliates', :controller => 'affiliates', :action => 'index'

map.essentials '/preferences/essentials', :controller => 'preferences/essentials', :action => 'index'
map.contacts '/preferences/contacts', :controller => 'preferences/contacts', :action => 'index'
map.travel '/preferences/travel', :controller => 'preferences/travel', :action => 'index'
map.online '/preferences/online', :controller => 'preferences/online', :action => 'index'
map.reminders '/preferences/reminders', :controller => 'preferences/reminders', :action => 'index'
map.miscellaneous '/preferences/miscellaneous', :controller => 'preferences/miscellaneous', :action => 'index'

map.home '/home', :controller => 'main', :action => 'home'
map.about '/about', :controller => 'main', :action => 'about'
map.gift '/gift', :controller => 'gift', :action => 'index'
map.plans '/plans', :controller => 'main', :action => 'plans'
map.faqs '/faqs', :controller => 'main', :action => 'faqs'
map.contact '/contact', :controller => 'main', :action => 'contact'

map.tos '/terms_of_service', :controller => 'main', :action => 'terms_of_service'
map.privacy '/privacy', :controller => 'main', :action => 'privacy'

map.root :controller => 'main'

map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

end

The complete error message from rails error log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/account/://0" with {:method=>:get}):
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/routing/recognition_optimisation.rb:66:in `recognize_path'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:386:in `recognize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:182:in `handle_request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in `dispatch_unlocked'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in `dispatch_cgi'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/usr/local/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Excerpt from apache vhost file:

```
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

  # Redirect all non-static requests to Mongrel
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://mongrel1%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

  <Proxy balancer://mongrel1>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3000
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / balancer://mongrel1/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mongrel1/
  ProxyPreserveHost on
```

Thanks!

Comment: Need more information like how you're getting that error. That'd be a good start.

Comment: People seem to be missing the fact that an actual request for /account/://0 is happening. Check the apache log files and see if there's any referer for those requests.

Answer (score 1):

Uh - the issue appears to be that someone is requesting a URL of `"/account/://0"`?  Why should that **not** produce a routing error?  I would not expect that to hit any route you've defined.

Answer (score 1):

Could this simply be a hacking attempt ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a problem inside your config/routes.rb file.

If you could add the contents of the routes.rb file and the URL you are trying to load to your message, we could help further.

Answer (score 0):

map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

Interchange these statements with order to given below.

map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

there are no restful routes, provided in routes.rb so the problem may not be of method defination, or calling any member method.

the format is just overriding the url source.